# iOS App with Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to upload an image that my iOS app captures to Flask -- I get an HTTP 500 error, the origin of which I do not understand.

Here's my code:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, Api, Resource
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

@app.route('/')
def projects():
    file = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        file = request.files['file']

    if file:
         img = Image.open(file)
         print("Image successfully loaded.")

    return render_template("home.html")

app.run(debug=True)
```

And for iOS:

```
func uploadImage(image: UIImage) -> Void{
        //Convert the image to a data blob
        guard let png = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else{
            print("error")
            return
        }

        //Set up a network request
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest()
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.url = NSURL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/") as! URL as! URL
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("\(png.count)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request.httpBody = png
        // Figure out what the request is making and the encoding type...

        //Execute the network request
        let upload = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request as URLRequest, from: png) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            //What you want to do when the upload succeeds or fails
        }

        upload.resume()

    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let img = UIImage(named: "messi.jpg")
    uploadImage(image: img!)

}
```

Any ideas?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: The error on the server I get is "builtins.UnboundLocalError UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment", but if I fix that I get "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateRuntimeError: extended multiple times."

The message I get on Xcode is "715863+0900 swiftServer[6240:329748] [] nw_socket_output_finished shutdown(8, SHUT_WR) [57: Socket is not connected]"

Answer (score 0):

You need to see the error message on the flask-side.

`HTTP 500` means *"Internal Server Error"*, and it means your flask app's error for now. Maybe you can find the detailed error messages on the console of your server.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry for not including this in my post, but the error on the server I get is "builtins.UnboundLocalError
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'file' referenced before assignment". Any ideas?

Comment: Variable `file` will be defined only if the request is POST request. So you have to handle the exception for the case of GET or other requests.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Are you saying I need to implement a GET function in the Flask file?

Comment: There are two points of considerations in your question. One thing is you didn’t consider the GET(or PUT, DELETE, ...) cases in your flask function. You have to handle them in your function or you will always get error messges for GET request. And another thing is it seems that your request from iOS did not work as POST request. It should work well if your request was POST request. You may have to check the request on the server side.